# pthread_exit from a function called from a thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Suppose i create a thread that ,in some point, calls a function foo().
If i call pthread_exit() from within foo, will that have as a result termination 
of the thread that called foo?

thanks,
Nikos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Otherwise what's the point of pthread_exit in the first place.
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html
"The pthread_exit() function shall terminate the calling thread"

Comment: what was the problem with the die.net link? :)

Comment: There have been complaints that the die.net man pages are out of date.  On a question like this it is probably irrelevant but a more authoritative source doesn't hurt.

Comment: Yes, some of us (yours truly) are on a crusade to fix the die.net links that keep it at the top of SEO despite being full of outdated information.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The pthread_exit() function terminates
>   the calling thread

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. It will also result in calling cleanup code, if any. Beware that it won't automatically clean application resources like mutexes etc. See [pthread_exit()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Except for robust mutexes - but using them for threads rather than processes would be rather wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - thread context is unaffected by call/return.  The thread IS calling pthread_exit(), no matter how long the call stack is.  If 20 threads call foo then all 20 threads will exit.

Rgds,
Martin